# jQuery submit with $_Get parameter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a form here:

```
<form method="post" name="work_form" action="<?php echo $link; ?>"
```

All is working OK and I have a separate jQuery that will also do the same submission and I have been reading on SOF and seems I can do something like this:

```
var action="activity.php?view&pid=1044&hash=bab54ffd80cc30083ffee373141a4926"; //same as php $link value//
$("form:work_form").attr('action', action).submit();
```

Which is suppose to simulate the submit. I have a issue here, when I do a normal submit from the usual

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
```

It is ok but if I trigger it from the jQuery, I only get this

```
http://www.myurl.com//activity.php?
```

The $_Get prefix is not pass.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like your action is being overwritting, but not by parameters since you are missing the "?" sign.

Try:

```
var action="?view&pid=1044&hash=bab54ffd80cc30083ffee373141a4926"; //same as php $link value//
$("form[name='work_form']").attr('action',action).submit();
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, same result still not passing.

Comment: Sorry I have a type for the "var action" but I have corrected it. However, I still have not figure out why the submission does not work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

@user1934737 
I have not tried your code but from the first instance I see that your form method is "POST" and you are trying $_GET in jquery. If you change your form method to "GET" does it show the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I have value in the from which I will retrieve from the php $_POST and I also have $_Get value. Actually come to think about it, I already have the action="<?php echo $link; ?> in the form so technically, I just need $("form:work_form").submit() will do?

Comment: I think maybe it is not the statement but something else, because I try to send $("form:work_form_testing").submit() which form work_form_testing do not exist and it still submit but probably don't know what form to call. Maybe that is the reason. I also try assign a ID to the form:<form method="post" id="mainwork_form" name="work_form" action="<?php echo $link; ?>" and call $('form#mainwork_form').submit(); but same result it is not working.

Comment: @user1934737 : Can you please provide your code and what you want exactly. In that way, I can code that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the reason so at the end I simulate the actual submit button click:

```
$('#work_form_save').click();
```